Calculating the Number of Segments in a Sphere Divided by Random Circles
I'm trying to determine the number of segments a sphere is divided into after intersecting it with a random number of random great circles. Specifically, if I have a sphere and I draw a set of great circles inside, where the number of circles and their positions are random, how can I calculate the total number of segments or regions created within the sphere?
I tried creating a formula and it looks like this: $ \frac{\left( x^{2} + n + 2 \right)} {2} $
but I'm not sure if it's correct.
Any insights into the formula or method to compute this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Why a downvote for a question attesting work ?
